# Gentoo emerge packages conflict

Tags: git, perl, gentoo

I'm trying to install git on my Gentoo webserver. The command "emerge dev-vcs/git" returns the following result :

```
 * IMPORTANT: 12 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.


 * IMPORTANT: 5 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.
 * See the CONFIGURATION FILES section of the emerge
 * man page to learn how to update config files.
Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] perl-core/parent-0.228-r1
[ebuild  N     ] perl-core/Data-Dumper-2.154.0
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-parent-0.228-r1
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Data-Dumper-2.154.0
[ebuild     U #] dev-lang/perl-5.20.2 [5.16.3] USE="-berkdb*"
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.10.0-r1
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-if-0.60.300
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Exporter-5.710.0-r1
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Carp-1.330.100
[ebuild  N     ] perl-core/CGI-4.90.0  USE="{-test}"
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-CGI-4.90.0
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Error-0.170.210  USE="{-test}"
[ebuild  N     ] dev-vcs/git-2.3.1  USE="blksha1 cgi curl gpg iconv nls pcre perl python threads webdav -cvs -doc -emacs -gnome-keyring -gtk -highlight -mediawiki (-ppcsha1) -subversion {-test} -tk -xinetd" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7"

!!! Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled
!!! into the dependency graph, resulting in a slot conflict:

dev-lang/perl:0

  (dev-lang/perl-5.16.3:0/5.16::gentoo, installed) pulled in by
    =dev-lang/perl-5.16* required by (virtual/perl-libnet-1.230.0:0/0::gentoo, installed)
    ^              ^^^^^                                                                                                   
    dev-lang/perl:0/5.16=[-build(-)] required by (perl-core/File-Temp-0.230.400-r1:0/0::gentoo, installed)
                 ^^^^^^^^                                                                                                  
    (and 12 more with the same problems)

  (dev-lang/perl-5.20.2:0/5.20::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    =dev-lang/perl-5.20* required by (virtual/perl-Carp-1.330.100:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
    ^              ^^^^^                                                                                                   
    (and 2 more with the same problem)


It may be possible to solve this problem by using package.mask to
prevent one of those packages from being selected. However, it is also
possible that conflicting dependencies exist such that they are
impossible to satisfy simultaneously.  If such a conflict exists in
the dependencies of two different packages, then those packages can
not be installed simultaneously. You may want to try a larger value of
the --backtrack option, such as --backtrack=30, in order to see if
that will solve this conflict automatically.

For more information, see MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge man
page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.
```

Following this, I tried to "emerge dev-lang/perl" but it returns the same error. Any tip ? Thanks guys !

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the Gentoo Perl upgrade news item. There is good additional background here: http://dilfridge.blogspot.com/2014/08/perl-in-gentoo-upgrading-pains-perl.html